# Error app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug FAILED

Tags: android, gradle, build, ads

If anyone had this error message

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForDebug'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:<app folder>\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\debug\28\com\google\ads\interactivemedia\v3\internal\aux.class (The system cannot find the file specified)

from this import

```
 implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.22.3'
```

Have tried clean/rebuild/invalid caches & restart, deleted .idea, .gradle, build files to rebuild it but it seems I can't get over the error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by updating the firebase plugin from 1.2.1 to 1.3.5 in gradle module

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.5'
```